# RestAssured with Serenity executing irrelevant test classes' @BeforeClass setup

Tags: rest-assured, serenity-bdd, serenity

I'm using RestAssured with Serenity to test my application's rest endpoints. I have used tags on my test classes. If I want to run a specific kind of test class, I use something like below

```
mvn clean verify -Dtags="myapp:users:get:list"
```

This works fine, but I've noticed that the setup section, annotated with @BeforeClass, of irrelevant classes also gets executed. Is this behavior normal, or have I missed something?